# Howlerjs playing audio twice when using once()

Tags: javascript, howler.js

I'm working with Howler.js on a little alarm clock I'm working on.

For my alarm clock, I want to play 2 audio files sequentially when the current time matches a predetermined time.

I've got this code:

```
var play_sound = window[data.sound];

presound.play();
presound.once('end', function(){
    play_sound.play();
});
```

The problem is, this code plays my `presound` 2 times, and then `play_sound` afterward. I do not want it to play the presound 2 times, only once.

If I change the code to

```
presound.play();
play_sound.play();
```

It seems to work, it doesn't play them at the same time, but I worry that it might in some cases. So I want to avoid these files being played at the same time, and I also want to avoid either of them playing more than once.

How can I do what I'm trying to do while utilizing events to make sure there is no overlap?

I also tried this:

```
presound.once('play', function() {
    presound.once('end', function() {
        play_sound.play();
    });
});

presound.play();
```

but it also plays my `presound` twice.

Comment: I believe you may be using the wrong event. Instead of `end` it should be `onend` per [the docs](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js#onend-function)

Comment: @SpencerPollock That's not what it says in the example `Listen for events:`. And if it was an incorrect event, wouldn't it throw an error?

Comment: You are going to provide a full test case because the code you are showing will only play the sound once, so there must be something else you are doing that is causing the problem.

Comment: @JamesSimpson That _is_ the full test case. When I use the event, it plays the presound twice, then it plays the `play_sound`. Without the event, it only plays each sound once.

Comment: That isn't the full test case because there is no way to take what you have and test it. It doesn't even include where the Howl gets setup.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js#listen-for-events) I can see another example with `end` event:

```
// Fires when the sound finishes playing.
sound.on('end', function(){
  console.log('Finished!');
});
```

Did you try `on` instead of `once`?

**UPD:**

Cannot reproduce an issue.

A code snippet that I use:

```js
function clickme() {
  var presound = new Howl({
    src: ['sound.m4a'],
    html5: true
  });

  var play_sound = new Howl({
    src: ['sound2.mp3'],
    html5: true
  });

  presound.play();

  // Fires when the sound finishes playing.
  presound.once('end', function() {
    play_sound.play();
  });
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/howler/2.1.1/howler.core.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" onclick="clickme()" value="Hello" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't want to use `on`, because I may call a different sound every time the function runs, if I used `on`, it would create a new event every time the function runs that would never go away